# How to get byte array form javafx.scene.image.Image object?

Tags: java, arrays, image

I want to save image into database. I have a Customer model that has Image property in it. I am creating a class that handle all the customer related database operations. In that class I have a method that takes in Customer object and inserts it into the database. Therefore, I have only Customer object to work with. How can I convert that Image object into byte array so that I can insert it into the datbase?

I know how to extract byte array from a file object. Should I change the customer model to contain image file instead of image object?

Comment: Can you upload your code.

Comment: I just want to know if I can get byte array from an Image object. I have not written any code for the database operations.

Comment: It's possible with a lot of various avenues. Here's a very basic intro to it: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/image-processing-java-set-1-read-write/

Read around and try to get a better idea of what exactly you want to do, then if you have issues with implementation or anything you can ask a more specific question.

Comment: I want to know if it is possible to get byte array from javafx.scene.image.Image?

Comment: Hey mate can you try with this ?

      BufferedImage bImage = ImageIO.read(new File("sample.jpg"));
      ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      ImageIO.write(bImage, "jpg", bos );
      byte [] data = bos.toByteArray();

Comment: If you're using JavaFX then you can use the [`PixelReader`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/PixelReader.html) and [`PixelWriter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/image/PixelWriter.html) interfaces. They have methods for reading and writing the pixel data using `byte[]`, `int[]`, `ByteBuffer`, or `IntBuffer`. Note that these won't be compressed (i.e. the data won't be in a format such as PNG or JPG). If you want to store the _file_ as bytes then you should do just that. If you don't have a file, see Mak's comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
Image image = customer.getImage();

BufferedImage bufferedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null);
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "jpeg", byteArrayInputStream);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
byte[] buffer = byteArrayInputStream.toByteArray();
```